# How to encode Python Decimal to Json Number

Tags: python, json, encoding, decimal, encode

How to convert `Decimal("123456789012345.99")` to json number **123456789012345.99**?

Python 3.11 win64

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal

class DecimalToFloat(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

class DecimalToStr(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

obj = {'decimal':Decimal("123456789012345.99")}

# {"decimal": 123456789012345.98} - WRONG!!!!
print(json.dumps(obj, cls=DecimalToFloat)) 

# {"decimal": "123456789012345.99"} - json string
print(json.dumps(obj, cls=DecimalToStr)) 

# ??? {"decimal": 123456789012345.99}
```

**UPD**

simplejson module is OK

```
# {"decimal": 123456789012345.99}
print(simplejson.dumps(obj, use_decimal=True))
```

Is there a way to do the same with the standard library without external dependencies?

Comment: You need to clarify what your assumptions are regarding where this JSON will end up. Does the recipeint have Python with Decimal? Does the recipient have access to an arbitrary precision library like Decimal? Since JSON does not natively support the concept of Decimal in the same way Python does, you need to articulate the differences. Or, use a Python native serialization type.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal


d = Decimal("123456789012345.99")

s = str(d)

json_obj = {"number": s}

json_str = json.dumps(json_obj)

print(json_str) # outputs: {"number": "123456789012345.99"}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good try at answering but this is not what the OP is after. How would this scale to a complex dict with nested values for example?